# Figure (tikzpicture) and table side-by-side with no sub-caption

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, floats

Sorry I tried to follow a few posts here similar to my problem but no luck so far. I'm a newbie so thanks in advance for any help.

There's one of the codes I tried.

```
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
\resizebox{0.45\textwidth}{!}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xlabel={x label},
            ylabel={y label},
            xmin=0, xmax=8,
            ymin=0, ymax=125,
            xtick={0,1,2,4,6,8},
            ytick={0,25,50,75,100,125},
            ymajorgrids=true,
            grid style=dashed,
        ]
        \addplot+[only marks]
            coordinates {
            (0.125,2.377)(0.25,4.83)(0.5,9.235)(0.75,11.456)(1,15.285)(2,120.095)(4,104.51)(6,90.157)(8,81.821)
            };
        \end{axis}
   \end{tikzpicture}
}
\resizebox{0.45\textwidth}{!}{%
    \begin{tabular}{lrr}
        \hline
        Column1 & Column2 & Column3 \\ \hline
        C0.125 & 2.377 & 182.0 \\
        C0.25 & 4.830 & 156.9 \\
        C0.5 & 9.235 & 115.0 \\
        C0.75 & 11.456 & 96.2 \\
        C1 & 15.285 & 70.9 \\
        C2 & 120.095 & 3.9 \\
        C4 & 104.510 & 0 \\
        C6 & 90.157 & 0 \\
        C8 & 81.821 & 0 \\ \hline
   \end{tabular}
}
\caption{Sample}
\end{figure}
```

I got this.

[image]

So how do I make them side by side, many thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You need to adjust the `baseline` key of the `tikzpicture`. `baseline` defines which y-coordinate inside the `tikzpicture` should be placed on the baseline of the text. Below I've set it to `current axis.outer east`, you can also use a specific length, e.g. `baseline=1.5cm` to fine tune placement.

It is also part of the story that for a `tabular`, the default behaviour is that the middle row is placed on the baseline of the surrounding text. You can change that with e.g. `\begin{tabular}[b]{lrr}`, where `b` indicates that the bottom row is placed on the baseline. `c` is the default there, the third choice is `t` for the top row.

Also, you don't really need the `\resizebox`es. The width of a `pgfplots` axis can be set with the `width` key, see code.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current axis.outer east)]
        \begin{axis}[
            width=0.5\textwidth, % added
            xlabel={x label},
            ylabel={y label},
            xmin=0, xmax=8,
            ymin=0, ymax=125,
            xtick={0,1,2,4,6,8},
            ytick={0,25,50,75,100,125},
            ymajorgrids=true,
            grid style=dashed,
        ]
        \addplot+[only marks]
            coordinates {
            (0.125,2.377)(0.25,4.83)(0.5,9.235)(0.75,11.456)(1,15.285)(2,120.095)(4,104.51)(6,90.157)(8,81.821)
            };
        \end{axis}
   \end{tikzpicture}\hfill
    \begin{tabular}{lrr}
        \toprule
        Column1 & Column2 & Column3 \\ \midrule
        C0.125 & 2.377 & 182.0 \\
        C0.25 & 4.830 & 156.9 \\
        C0.5 & 9.235 & 115.0 \\
        C0.75 & 11.456 & 96.2 \\
        C1 & 15.285 & 70.9 \\
        C2 & 120.095 & 3.9 \\
        C4 & 104.510 & 0 \\
        C6 & 90.157 & 0 \\
        C8 & 81.821 & 0 \\ \bottomrule
   \end{tabular}
\caption{Sample}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 for  removing `\resizebox` :-)